How to change font color in the middle of a letter and match it with background colors?
I want to make text that changes its color in the middle of a word, in fact in the middle of a letter. I got it to work, but I also want to add a background color that changes in the same place. The issue is that I've used background image with a gradient to have the text colors change.
This is what I have so far with Tailwind CSS:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<span class="bg-[linear-gradient(to_right,black_23%,pink_23%)] bg-clip-text text-[100px] text-transparent">powered</span>






You can use a combination of CSS properties including background-clip and tailwind css to achieve this.


.gradient-text-bg {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: transparent;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, black 23%, pink 23%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
    }

    .gradient-text-bg::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue 23%, yellow 23%);
      z-index: -1;
      clip-path: text;
      -webkit-clip-path: text;
      -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    }
<div class="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
  <span class="gradient-text-bg">powered</span>
</div>



